# Issue when adding new Activity in Android Studio 1.3.2

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I have a strange problem when adding new Activity in **Android Studio 1.3.2** (not error with older versions):

If `dimens.xml` file inside `"\app\src\main\res\values-w820dp"` is **READ-ONLY**, when add new Activity (`File - New - Activity...`), only menu xml file created, `AndroidManifest.xml` updated, but ...Activity.java and layout xml not created.

Like the following screenshot:

[image]

If unset read-only from that `dimens.xml` file, everything works normally. I really don't understand why so. Since after the activity created, I find `"Date-modified"` or `"Accesed"` property of `dimens.xml` not changed.

Comment: Might be best to move this to the Android Studio bug tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the developers made auto-creation of the resources comes ahead before the java file, and it encountered uncaught File exception during creation. So basically, when it tried to execute the command of writing **dimens.xml** it throws an exception because it can't be written, everything else except what's ahead the xml is not created. As for why date-modified did not change, it is because it checks the content before writing in which, if it has the value *activity_horizontal_margin*, the writing for that xml cancels/exits. Try removing it, you will see the date modified if you reproduce the event. And yes, this should be reported as bug.